# Tengo un problema inesperado Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para android y de un momento a otro al probarla despues de unos minutos me lanza este error, lo malo es que no se de donde se origina, alguna solución? Gracias por adelantado!!

El problema es:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at
com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:157)
at
android.widget.Toast.getLooper(Toast.java:179) at
android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:164)
at
android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:492)
at
android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:480) at
com.in.app.Sketchware Util.showMessage(SketchwareUtil.java:157)
at
com.in.app.SketchLogger$1.run(SketchLogger.java:48)
```

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido a StackOverflow. ¿Qué código estas utilizando? ¿Dónde falla? Por favor, lee [ask] para tener una mejor visión de como preguntar. ¡Así podremos ayudarte!

Comment: Es muy importante agregar el còdigo, agrega como estas llamando el Toast.

Comment: @Tupi Gracias, el problema es que no se exactamente en que parte de codigo falla, utilizo java
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at com.android.internal.util.Prec onditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:157)
at android.widget.Toast.getLooper(Toast.java:179) at
android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:164)
at android.widget.Toast.makeT ext(Toast.java:492)
at android.widget.Toast.makeT ext(Toast.java:480) at
com.in.app.Sketchware Util.showMessage(SketchwareUtil.java:157)
at com.in.app.SketchLogger$1.run(SketchLogger.java:48)`

Comment: El problema es al tratar de crear el Toast, estas creando el toast en un Fragment o en una Activity? agreguè respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

```
Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Esto sucede cuando intentas llamar a un Toast desde un Thread que **NO ES** el UIThread. El toast al ser un componente visual **deberia** llamarse desde el UIThread.

Si de momento no esta seguro desde donde viene ese error. El logcat te puede ayudar como puedes ver en la siguiente linea de error.

```
android.widget.Toast.makeT ext(Toast.java:492) at android.widget.Toast.makeT ext(Toast.java:480) at com.in.app.Sketchware Util.showMessage(SketchwareUtil.java:157)
```

Me parece que el error esta en la `linea 157` del archivo `SketchwareUtil`

Busca en ese archivo como se llama el Toast y verifica desde que Thread se esta llamando.

Como un workaround puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't toast on a thread that has not
> called Looper.prepare()

Indica que no puedes mostrar un Toast en un subproceso que no sea de interfaz de usuario. Debe llamar a `Toast.makeText()` desde el hilo principal.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {

         Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hola Angel Del Valle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
 });
```